# How to declare field-level type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

In the following code sniplet, I want to specify that:

1. `attachment` and `handler` share a generic type `
2. `<A>`'s type only needs to be specified when `notify()` is invoked
3. Invoking `notify()` is optional.

I do not want to force users to specify `<A>` at class construction time because they might never end up invoking `notify()`.

```
/**
 * Builder pattern for some asynchronous operation.
 */
public class OperationBuilder
{
  private A attachment = null;
  private CompletionHandler<Integer, A> handler = null;

  public <A> OperationBuilder notify(A attachment, CompletionHandler<Integer, A> handler)
  {
    this.attachment = attachment;
    this.handler = handler;
    return this;
  }

  public abstract build();
}
```

Is this possible under Java? If not, what would you recommend I do?

**UPDATE**: I don't need to specify that `<A>` associated with `attachment` and `handler` must be the same `<A>` associated with `notify()`. All I'm trying to specify is that `attachment` and `handler` must use the same type `<A>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is to have notify() return a bridge object that is typed with `A`. Something along these lines:

```
  public class OperationBuilder
  {

    public Bridge<A> OperationBuilder notify(A a, CompletionHandler<Integer, A> h)
    {
       return new Bridge<A>(a, h);
    }

    protected abstract<A> void build(Bridge<A> b);



    public class Bridge<A>
    {
        private A attachment;
        private CompletionHandler<Integer, A> handler;

        public Bridge(A a, CompletionHandler<Integer, A> h)
        {
           attachment = a;
           handler = h;
        }


        public void build()
        {
           build(this); // Will invoke OperationBuilder.build()
        }               
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class OperationBuilder 
{ 
  private Object attachment = null; 
  private Object handler = null; 

  public <A> OperationBuilder notify(A attachment, CompletionHandler<Integer, A> handler) 
  { 
    this.attachment = attachment; 
    this.handler = handler; 
    return this; 
  } 
}
```

If you wanted to later use `attachment`/`handler`, you'd have to cast them to the appropriate type at that time, which could lead to runtime type-conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible under Java?

No – `A` would have to be known to the class (since it’s used in a *member* of said class).

> If not, what would you recommend I do?

You probably don’t need the generic type here. Use an interface or `Object`. If type safety is important for the interface, you may simply use casts.